# JPA Repository Internals - How JpaRepository works internally?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

[Communication problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bN7S.png)

Suppose we have a class named IpeopleRepository that extends JpaRepository.That class has no actual relation with neither SimpleJpaRepository nor SimpleJpaNoCountRepository, but still it has an access to it's native methods.
My question is :
There is obviously an assignment such as "if there is no implementation of JpaRepository ,then use SimpleJpaRepository as it's default implementation".How such configuration is made ? It seems like an autowire structure (in terms of Spring bean context).
The image that describes the relation between repositories can be found under "communication problem" put above .